# How to get the java path in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

This is my project structure in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

I can use below code to get the `webapp` path, but I don't know how to get the `java` path.

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

Someone know how to get the path?

Comment: what's in src/main/java is compiled, so why do you need this path?

Comment: I would guess that if you need that source path, you have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Your purpose is to get this path in the jsp page?Get this path, not much use

Comment: @AxelH what mean? my friend.

Comment: You have the package information with [`Class.getPackage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getPackage()). Do what you want with that, don't hope to update the code like this, you will need a script to build the web app and redeploy the new war to your server

Comment: @Ipgad, I just want to know can I get that path in JSP. I am not sure.

Comment: When you've compiled and bundled your application the paths can be completely different. `src/main/java` contains _source_ code (and packages) and is most likely _not_ present in the final artifact (jar, war, ear, etc.). Those paths are used by the build tool (it looks like Maven in your case) and when the application is compiled the `.class` files are moved from `src/main/java` etc. to `target` and then into the artifact. What do you need that path for?

Comment: @AxelH Oh, that is mean in java-web project , in general we do not need the `src/main/java` path, right?

Comment: You can write java scripts in the jsp page to get the path, for example <% ... code.%>

Comment: I still don't get what exactly are you trying to do. Read Java source files, read files from the webapp, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest information you can have is the package of a class that you can get with [`Class.getPackage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getPackage()).

> public Package getPackage()
>
> Gets the package for this class. The class loader of this class is used to find the package. If the class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader the set of packages loaded from CLASSPATH is searched to find the package of the class. Null is returned if no package object was created by the class loader of this class. 
>   Packages have attributes for versions and specifications only if the information was defined in the manifests that accompany the classes, and if the class loader created the package instance with the attributes from the manifest.
>
> Returns:the package of the class, or null if no package information is available from the archive or codebase.

Of course this won't be the absolute path.

PS : Not sure what you want to do with this but this should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know some basic rules. JSP is used from  front end, thus is used for client side. Although JSP in turn transforms into executable Java Servlets and itself interacts with server(dynamic pages), but you need to understand that if the JSP has a direct source code linkage, then what security will java provide. Anyone can write the malicious code and interact with the actual source code. Thats why it uses the byte code (compiled code) and have its own directory structure. 
Hope that helps

Comment: whats mean of front end?

Comment: "client-side development" (View in MVC)